# Web.API, ASP .NET MVC and ModelState error mapping

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, automapper, modelstate

To give a bit of context first, we have an MVC application plugged to a Web API which itself communicate with at least a SQL Sever DB via Entity Framework; communication goes both way as users can edit the data.

There is validation, via data annotation, on all the layers, that's is Db Models, DTOs and ViewModels, which is for the most part the same on every layer, non null-able, minimum length, that sort of thing. We do however have some peculiar, complex, ever changing business logic that we decided to implement only in the Web API.

The validation errors are returned from the Web API using:

```
Request.CreateErrorResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, ModelState);
```

Some custom header allow the HttpClient's wrapper on the MVC side to handle the response as an error cast the content by into a ModelStateDictionnary

My question(s) relate to the ModelState error targeted property name, since DTOs and the ViewModel aren't exactly the same, I need to map the ModelState error so it will point to the ViewModel property instead of the DTO, for example, if I receive the following ModelState from the Web API :

```
{"CustomerDTO.full_name", "The full name needs to be unique"}
```

I need it to become:

```
{"CustomerViewModel.FullName", "The full name needs to be unique"}
```

So it can be displayed at the right place on the views.

At the moment I'm doing this manually, like the initial DTO to ViewModel object mapping, and ,unless my Google-fu teachings failed me, there doesn't seem to be any way in .NET to do so automatically, arguably there is no object mapping either, but I was planning on trying AutoMapper to map the objects together and then reuse the mapping for the ModelState errors.

Now before I waste 3 days on this, probably banging my head on the desk a couple of time in the process, has anybody encountered that problem before ? Does that look like a sound approach ? If not is there a better solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Web Api acts like a REST api to talk to the db. You should not directly connecting anything(DTO's etc) from this to your MVC which makes both  tightly coupled. I would recommend keeping the data annotation attributes on both set of DTO's. Obviously your MVC app's view model might be slightly different than your ViewModel's for Web Api i guess.

If it is all in the same solution and you want same DTO' for both MVC and Web API, you can create a new Common Project in the same solution and drop the DTO's there and refer this project in both the places.

The important thing to remember is, you need to validate your input in your WebApi all the time. Do not trust what is being posted to it from your mvc app.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, but yes obviously the Web API is a REST API and the MVC communicates with it via an HTTPClient, the only thing in common between the two are the DTOs which act as model for the MVC and ViewModels for the Web API.

Comment: Aslo there is the same validation on all levels, but there is more in the Web API, some validations I can't put everywhere, a good example of that is unique, I let the database handle the uniqueness of a field, what I'm looking for is the way to map the column name to corresponding dto property, then to the corresponding viewmodel property

Comment: Here changed the original post for some clarity